Problems using Vim to yank to clipboard
I can't seem to yank to clipboard within Vim on Ubuntu (Windows Subsystem for Linux).  I am pressing "+y and it's giving me the regular X lines yanked, instead of X lines yanked into "+ to show that the yanked contents are in the clipboard.
I've run vim --version | grep 'clipboard' and confirmed that there is a + next to clipboard.  I've run sudo apt-get install vim-gtk3.  I've added set clipboard=unnamedplus into my .vimrc.  What else could I be missing?  Thanks in advance.
Here's my .vimrc:
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required
 
" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')
 
" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
 

Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Plugin 'ervandew/supertab'
 
 
" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
"filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line
 
filetype on
filetype indent on
syntax enable
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=2
syn on
set expandtab
autocmd FileType make setlocal noexpandtab
set showmatch
set background=dark
 
set number
colorscheme desert
highlight Normal ctermbg=NONE
highlight nonText ctermbg=NONE
 
set clipboard=unnamedplus
 
"----------------------
"Syntastic settings 
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*
 
let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0


This question is similar to: Vim on WSL: synchronize system clipboard? (set clipboard^=unnamed)?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Unrelated but you should note that Syntastic was deprecated a while ago. Its maintainers recommend ALE.

Thank you for the heads up on Syntastic, as well as the link to the related question.  That helped tremendously!

These are the relevant parts of my setup which works fine on WSL, Windows, Linux and Android (termux). You might want to strip out the IsWSL function if you don't need it.
" For WSL conditionals
function! IsWSL()
  if has("unix")
    if filereadable("/proc/version") " avoid error on Android
      let lines = readfile("/proc/version")
      if lines[0] =~ "microsoft"
        return 1
      endif
    endif
  endif
  return 0
endfunction

" Set clipboard on WSL
if has('unix') && IsWSL()==1
  let g:clipboard = {
                  \   'name': 'WslClipboard',
                  \   'copy': {
                  \      '+': 'clip.exe',
                  \      '*': 'clip.exe',
                  \    },
                  \   'paste': {
                  \      '+': 'powershell.exe -c [Console]::Out.Write($(Get-Clipboard -Raw).tostring().replace("`r", ""))',
                  \      '*': 'powershell.exe -c [Console]::Out.Write($(Get-Clipboard -Raw).tostring().replace("`r", ""))',
                  \    },
                  \   'cache_enabled': 0,
                  \ }
endif


Thanks, just tested this out and it works as well!
